# Open new terminal tab/window using CLI

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

Is there any command that opens a new terminal tab or window and runs another command, eg. `less +F ~/log.txt` in the new tab/window?

Answer (score 1):

Consider utilizing [`osascript`](https://ss64.com/osx/osascript.html) to execute an Applescript.

For instance in your *Terminal* application run the following command:

```sh
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "less +F ~/log.txt"'
```

This will create a new *Terminal* window and run the `less +F ~/log.txt` command.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I could use this for other operating systems besides macOS? Linux and Windows basically.

Comment: No, `osascript` exists on mac only. Why have you tagged your question with `macos` tag?

Comment: @RobC or tmux for a more modern version. Personally I use :term in vim which gives me even more capabilities.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn - Sure - I didn't mention that because macOS doesn't ship with builtin `tmux` - a `$ brew install tmux` is required.

Answer (score 0):

This comes to my mind from old days ...

```
xterm -e program [options]
```